# when i pull the image data it is not showing from duckduckgo api

Tags: node.js

I am using node.js , microsoft bot framework and duckduckgo api , i want to show the image result based from the question i got the asnwer text and url but image is not showing in my bot. Thank You. i have provided the code below [image: imagescreenshot1][image: image2]

```
if (session.userData.search === 'DuckDuckGo') {

        request = require('request');
        var url = "https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=" + encodeURIComponent(messageText) + "&format=json&pretty=1";
        console.log("data:", messageText);
        request(url, function(err, response, body) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                body = JSON.parse(body)
                session.sendTyping();
                console.log(body);
                if (!_.isEmpty(body.AbstractText)) {
                    session.send(body.AbstractText);
                    session.send(body.Image);
                } else if (!_.isEmpty(body.RelatedTopics[0])) {
                    session.send(body.RelatedTopics[0].Icon.URL);
                    session.send(body.RelatedTopics[0].Text);
                      session.send(body.RelatedTopics[0].Icon);
                      console.log("data1111" , body.RelatedTopics[0].Icon);
                    console.log("tubag:", body.RelatedTopics[1].Text);
                   /* session.send("Related Results");*/
                  /*  builder.Prompts.send(body.RelatedTopics[1].Text)
                    builder.Prompts.text(session, body.RelatedTopics[2].Text)
                    builder.Prompts.text(session, body.RelatedTopics[3].Text)*/

                } else {
                    session.send('https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s', encodeURIComponent(messageText));
                }

            } else if (response.statusCode == 500) {
                session.send("error: server error");

            } else {
                session.send("error: problem with request code: " + response.statusCode)

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible of a blank URL for the image/icon. If there is no image URL provided, no image attachment will be made or sent by the bot with this example.

```
request = require('request');
var url = "https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=" + encodeURIComponent(messageText) + "&format=json&pretty=1";
console.log("data:", messageText);
request(url, function(err, response, body) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        body = JSON.parse(body)
        session.sendTyping();
        console.log(body);
        if (!_.isEmpty(body.AbstractText)) {
            session.send(body.AbstractText);
            session.send(body.Image);
        } else if (!_.isEmpty(body.RelatedTopics[0])) {
            session.send(body.RelatedTopics[0].Icon.URL);
            session.send(body.RelatedTopics[0].Text);
              session.send(body.RelatedTopics[0].Icon);
              console.log("data1111" , body.RelatedTopics[0].Icon);
            console.log("tubag:", body.RelatedTopics[1].Text);
           /* session.send("Related Results");*/
          /*  builder.Prompts.send(body.RelatedTopics[1].Text)
            builder.Prompts.text(session, body.RelatedTopics[2].Text)
            builder.Prompts.text(session, body.RelatedTopics[3].Text)*/

        } else {
            session.send('https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s', encodeURIComponent(messageText));
        }

    } else if (response.statusCode == 500) {
        session.send("error: server error");

    } else {
        session.send("error: problem with request code: " + response.statusCode)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is an image that the bot is trying to send, you would need to send this as an attachment via the bot's message.

Images can also be jpeg, gif, or png from this API (unless they can also return SVG, I haven't used the DuckDuckGo API before).  So I've added a way to use the proper MIME type based on the extension of the URL (or default to image/jpeg if there's no match) in the

Finally, there's the possibility of a blank URL for the image/icon.  If there is no image URL provided, no image attachment will be made or sent by the bot with this example.

Try this:

```
request = require('request');
var url = "https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=" + encodeURIComponent(messageText) + "&format=json&pretty=1";
console.log("data:", messageText);
request(url, function(err, response, body) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        session.sendTyping();
        console.log(body);
        if (!_.isEmpty(body.AbstractText)) {
            session.send(body.AbstractText);
            session.send(body.Image);
        } else if (!_.isEmpty(body.RelatedTopics[0])) {
            session.send(body.RelatedTopics[0].Icon.URL);
            session.send(body.RelatedTopics[0].Text);

            let imageSourceUrlArray = body.RelatedTopics[0].Icon.URL.split(".");
            let imageType = "";
            let imageExtension = "";
            if (imageSourceUrlArray.length > 1){
                imageType = imageSourceUrlArray[imageSourceUrlArray.length - 1];
            }

            // Get the proper image mime type based on extension.
            switch (imageExtension) {
                case "jpg":
                case "jpeg":
                imageType = "image/jpeg";
                break;
                case "gif":
                imageType = "image/gif";
                break;
                case "png":
                imageType = "image/png";
                break;
                default:
                imageType = "image/jpeg";
                break;
            }

            // If there's a valid image url, send it as an attachment.
            if (!!body.RelatedTopics[0].Icon.URL) {
                let image = new builder.Message(session).attachments([{
                    contentType: imageType, 
                    contentUrl: body.RelatedTopics[0].Icon.URL
                }]);

                session.send(image);
            }

                //session.send(body.RelatedTopics[0].Icon);
                console.log("data1111" , body.RelatedTopics[0].Icon);
            console.log("tubag:", body.RelatedTopics[1].Text);
            /* session.send("Related Results");*/
            /*  builder.Prompts.send(body.RelatedTopics[1].Text)
            builder.Prompts.text(session, body.RelatedTopics[2].Text)
            builder.Prompts.text(session, body.RelatedTopics[3].Text)*/

        } else {
            session.send('https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s', encodeURIComponent(messageText));
        }

    } else if (response.statusCode == 500) {
        session.send("error: server error");

    } else {
        session.send("error: problem with request code: " + response.statusCode);

    }
});
```

I implemented this for the related topic branch, but this can be easily added to the `if (!_.isEmpty(body.AbstractText))` branch as well (with the `body.Image` part).

Also, my modifications are using ES6.  If you prefer not to use that, or if you're using Internet Explorer, change `let` to `var`.

Comment: Thanks for this  Sir.